# DataGridView, CellEnter causes "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function"

Tags: c#, datagridview

When performing a CellEnter on a DataGridView I get the following error:

```
Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the    
SetCurrentCellAddressCore function
```

The grid is used to edit one page of data at a time.  The following variables are used:

```
a  = two dimensional array of data
cp = current page
np = number of pages
pp = rows per page
tr = index of top row on the page
br = index of bottom row on the page 
r  = total number of rows of data
s  = stores value of current cell
```

Here is the code:

```
    private void chkAddRow()
    {
        dgv1.AllowUserToAddRows = (cp == np) && (dgv1.RowCount < pp);
    }
    private void dgv1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string v;
        int br;
        int j;
        br = tr + e.RowIndex;
        if (br < r)
        {
            v = Convert.ToString(dgv1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(v))
                s = "0";
            else
                s = v;
        }
        else if (br == r)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            {
                if (j != e.ColumnIndex)
                {
                    dgv1[j, e.RowIndex].Value = "0";
                    a[r, j] = 0;
                }
            }
            dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = br.ToString();
            chkAddRow();
            r++;
        }
    }
```

Specifically the error occurs when setting AllowUserToAddRows to false, which occurs when editing the last allowed row in the grid e.g. when RowCount == pp.

How can I get around this problem and disable the adding of a new row when the RowCount reaches pp?

Thanks.

Comment: If your code needs a legend for what the variables mean, then you aren't naming your variables correctly.  You should probably use classes to model this information.  The temporary new row that is visible when AllowUserToAddRows is true is causing you problems because it can count in the RowCount property.  You can't turn that off when the user is in that row.